# can we post/put/delete using jsonp-cross domain in asp.net webapi?

Tags: cross-domain, jsonp, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Using asp.net webApi

I've site1 (http://localhost:53723) and site2 (http://localhost:64009).
I want to fetch data from site2 to site1 (Cross domain, not same origin).

We can use jsonp for this, and I've achieved data.

Can we use jsonp to post/put/delete verb for cross domain (not same origin)?

Comment: I think your architecture is flawed. Use different-origin only as an exception and not as a rule.

Comment: I want to make one source for all information (webapi) and use multiple platform to use it (website, mobile app, desktop app, etc)

This'll be cross-domain because i'll keep my webapi as one site and others platform in different site/app store/pc/mac.
So fetching from cross-domain is no issue, but what if i need post/put/delete action?

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Your design might be a little bit flawed and you should reconsider if you really need to make cross-origin requests. If you do, then a lot better solution in case when you need to support POST/PUT/DELETE verbs is [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/). Carlos Figueira have some nice blog post on how to implement it in ASP.NET Web API:

- [Implementing CORS support in ASP.NET Web APIs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/20/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis.aspx)
- [Implementing CORS support in ASP.NET Web APIs – take 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/21/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis-take-2.aspx)

Comment: Though CORS is nice and easy to implement, it will not work for cross protocol (http-https) requests for IE8/9. So to get it working the only available option in this case is still JSONP.